# pecl default php ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, pecl, gearman

I'm trying to install gearman in Ubuntu 16 LTS.

PECL won't install gearman for 7.0 with message:

```
pecl/gearman requires PHP (version >= 5.1.0, version <= 6.0.0,
excluded versions: 6.0.0), installed version is
7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
No valid packages found
```

Install failed with above message. However I'm using 5.6 with apache.

Is there a way to run gearman on my computer and install it using pecl?

Comment: Use a PPA that actually provides PECL for PHP7 instead: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I ran apt-get php-gearman and it seems to have installed. thanks